# jquery hash tag animation on select

Tags: jquery

My hash tag transition doesn't work, any ideas?

I have:

```
//Hash tag animations
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectcitydd').localScroll({duration:800, hash:true});
});
```

And this should be triggered by select:

```
<select id="selectcitydd">
<option selected="selected" value="http://localhost/wordpress/#afterheadindex">Tbilisi</option>
<option value="http://localhost/wordpress/gudauri/#afterheadindex">Gudauri</option>
<option value="http://localhost/wordpress/batumi/#afterheadindex">Batumi</option>
</select>
```

I use this jquery to trigger select url:

```
// Homepage Select City function
$(document).ready(function() {
  // bind change event to select
  $('#selectcitydd').on('change', function () {
      var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
      if (url) { // require a URL
          window.location = url; // redirect
      }
      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: could you create a demo on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?? Would be much easier to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try?

```
//document.ready
$(function(){
    $.localScroll.hash();
});
```

I guess by doing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectcitydd').localScroll({duration:800, hash:true});
});
```

you tell the plugin to scroll on `#selectcitydd` instead of the window.

So to preserve the duration you specified you'd have to write it like

```
$.localScroll.hash({
    target: '#content', // Could be a selector or a jQuery object too.
    queue:true,
    duration:800
});
```

I never actually used it, but just [checked out the sample](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll/blob/master/demo/index.html) on the GitHub repo.